# Lyx code tag with highlighting for C

Tags: listings, lyx, highlighting, code

I just installed Lyx and when I try to insert the program I observe that there is no syntax highlighting. What is the best way to allow for syntax highlighting in LYX?

Comment: LyX is a LaTeX code editor, but I think it's not designed for program listings in other languages. Or do you want to use a listing inside a (La)TeX document?

Comment: Its the latter. I have some code which I need to insert

Comment: I think, the LyX experts will know some solution to this, but you will need the `listings` package for highlighting in the document itself.

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence LyX is not really a LaTeX code editor. Insert --> Program listings uses the `listings` package, so it's just a matter of setting it up correctly in Document --> Settings --> Listings.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You know more of it, definitely. I never used LyX

Comment: @Sab By the way, will C be the only programming language you will show code from in the document?

Comment: Yes. I only need to highlight for C programs

Comment: I don't understand. Do you wan to have syntax highlighting when you are typing in LyX? That is not supported in LyX. I would suggest you type the programs in an IDE. Do you mean you want to have syntax highlighting in the output PDF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you need highlighted code in the PDF. When you do Insert --> Program listing, or if you insert a child document as a Program listing, it is the features of the `listings` package that is used. The look of all listings in a document can be modified under Document --> Settings --> Listings, where you can add any of the `<key>=<value>` pairs listed in [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf).

For example, to specify that the language is C, add `language=C`, to say that comments should be italic and yellow, add `commentstyle=\color{yellow}\itshape`, and so on. Again, the manual is the reference. (I've never really used it much myself.)

By adding something like

```
language=C,keywordstyle=\color{blue},
commentstyle=\color{magenta}\itshape,
emphstyle=\color{red},
breaklines,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
stringstyle=\color{green},
identifierstyle=\color{cyan}
```

to the settings, this hello world [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#.22Hello.2C_world.22_example) (with an added comment) turns out as shown below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// comment!

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

[image]